# JS async parallel control flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel

Салют народ! Есть такая задачка - необходимо реализовать функцию parallel, которая выполняет асинхронные операции параллельно. Функция `parallel` принимает два аргумента: массив операций и результирующий `callback`. В зависимости от результата работы функции (сработала или вышла с ошибкой) нужно вызвать соответствующий `callback`.
1) Передан пустой массив - вернуть `callback` с пустым массивом
2) В одной из функций ошибка - вернуть ошибку один раз
3) Если все операции завершились успешно, в `callback` передаётся первым аргументом `null`, а вторым – массив с результатами выполнения операций. Порядок данных должен соответствовать порядку операций в массиве, а не их вызову.

Задача проверяется на стороне сервера - вижу только ошибку, которую он выдает, а именно

> Failed tests: должна сохранять данные в правильном порядке

Видимо где то меня подвела строка `results.splice(operations.indexOf(fn),0,result);`

```
  module.exports = function (operations, callback) {
callback = callback || function(){};
var index = 0;//контроль итерации по массиву
var stop = 0;//контроль о выдаче только одного колбека с ошибкой, при наличии нескольких асинхронных функций с ошибкой
var results = [];//массив результатов
if(!operations.length){//проверка на пустой массив
    return callback(null,results);
}
operations.forEach(function(fn){
    fn(function(err, result){
        if(err && stop == 0){//проверка на то, является ли данная ошибка первой
            callback(err);
                callback = function(){};
                stop++;

        }else{
            index++;
            results.splice(operations.indexOf(fn),0,result);//вставка в массив на позицию в очереди вызовов
            if(index >=operations.length){//возврат результата, в случае последней итерации
                callback(null,results);
            }
        }
    });
});
stop = 0;
```

};

Не гневайтесь, если постановка вопроса показалась Вам не корректна - я только учусь) Если у Вас есть комментарии по качеству и стилю кода - тоже рад услышать!
За + буду признателен! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function run (arr, callback) {
  if (!arr.length)
    return callback(arr) // передаем этот же массив, не надо создавать новый []
    
  try {
    arr = arr.map(fun => fun())
  } catch (e) {
    return e
  }
  
  return callback(null, arr)
}

// выведет результат
run([
  () => 5 + 5, 
  () => 5 - 5
], (myNull, results) => console.log(results))

// будет ошибка
const resultWithErr = run(
  (a) => a
)
console.log(resultWithErr.message) // сообщение об ошибке
```

Если нужно передавать аргументы функциям:

```js
function run (arr, callback) {
  if (!arr.length)
    return callback(arr) // передаем этот же массив, не надо создавать новый []
    
  try {
    arr = arr.map(arr2 => arr2[0](...arr2.slice(1)))
  } catch (e) {
    return e
  }
  
  return callback(null, arr)
}

// выведет результат
run([
  [(a, b) => a + b, 5, 5], 
  [(a, b) => a - b, 20, 10],
  [(...num) => num.reduce((a, b) => a * b), 2, 2, 5, 5] // 2 * 2 * 5 * 5
], (myNull, results) => console.log(results))
```

Comment: Илья, спасибо - понял, что эту тему стоит еще "покурить"..

Comment: Можете принять ответ(нажать галочку), чтобы люди видели как правильней делать, он как и ваш делает все синхронно в отличие от ответа с Promise, но мой короче и понятней.

Comment: Это неправильное решение. Тут нет асинхронного контроля. Если передавать массив асинхронных задач, то результат undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Круто что ты учишься и пишешь так много кода. Но вся твоя задача решается в пару строчек:

```js
function asyncOperations(operations, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(operations) && operations.length < 1) {
    return callback([]);
  }

  Promise.all(operations).then(function(results) {
    callback(results);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return callback(error);
  })
}
```

Может работает не в точности так, как ты хочешь, но двигаться тебе нужно именно в этом направлении. Вот ссылка на документацию по промисам: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Салют! Согласен, с promise выглядит все гораздо проще. Просто хотелось попробовать реализовать именно через цепочки callback'ов. Чтобы уже усвоить их под капотную часть) Ведь, насколько я понял, при их минусах (высокий уровень вложенности, много переменных и т.д.) есть и плюсы - самый главный из них, высокая производительность.

Answer (score 0):

Тем кому будет интересно - задачу все же сумел реализовать через callback'и  - узкое место, как я и подозревал, была операция вставки в массив:

```
results.splice(operations.indexOf(fn),0,result);
```

В следствии не корректного обращения к массиву, при параллельном вызове, происходило искажение порядка вставки в финальный массив
Решение - изначально массиву results задается длина, равная длине массива функций.

```
results.length = operations.length;
```

Таким образом при повторном обращении к массиву results, не происходит перезаписи. Финальный код прикладываю ниже. Всем спасибо!

```
module.exports = function (operations, callback) {
callback = callback || function(){};
var index = 0;//контроль итерации по массиву
var stop = 0;//контроль о выдаче только одного колбека с ошибкой, при наличии нескольких асинхронных функций с ошибкой
var results = [];//массив результатов
if(!operations.length){//проверка на пустой массив
    return callback(null,results);
}
operations.forEach(function(fn){
    fn(function(err, result){
        if(err && stop == 0){//проверка на то, является ли данная ошибка первой
            callback(err);
                callback = function(){};
                stop++;

        }else{
            index++;
            results.length = operations.length;
            results.splice(operations.indexOf(fn),0,result);//вставка в массив на позицию в очереди вызовов
            if(index >=operations.length){//возврат результата, в случае последней итерации
                callback(null,results);
            }
        }
    });
});
stop = 0;
```

};

Comment: Ваш вариант выполняет асинхронные операции паралельно, в отличио от Promise